# Getting name of specific linq to sql table

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I am using Linq to SQL to manipulate and MS Access database.

To speed up batch modifications I found it more efficient to directly execute queries using the datacontext, like so `context.ExecutCommand("DELETE FROM [MyTable];")`. For the sake of efficiency I'd like to make this an extension method, but I don't know how to retrieve the table name from the context...

I know I could just pass the table name as a hardcoded string, something like:

```
public static void DeleteAll(this Table<TEntity> MyTable)
{
    string tableName = // retrieve MyTable's name

    MyTable.Context.ExecuteCommand(string.Format("DELETE FROM [{0}];", tableName));
}
```

I got some way towards getting the table name, but need some help to get thsi working. So far I have:

```
var tableName = dc.MyTables.Context.GetTable(typeof(MyTable)).ElementType.Name;
```

But can't figure out how to retrieve the type of the entities in `MyTables` so as not have to hardcode the argument of `.GetTable()` and make this usable for any table I pass in.

Any answer in C# or VB is fine. Thanks.

EDIT

To summarise what I am looking for is a way to get the entity type of a table, from the table itself. Something like `Context.MyTable.GetEntityType()`... if only it were that easy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure if this works for EF, but I use this approach in Linq to Sql.

You'll have to use attributes from `System.Data.Linq.Mapping` namespace. If you open the `*.designer.cs` file, containing the definition of any Linq to Sql entity, you'll find a line like this above the declaration of the class:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="YourTableName")]
```

So each entity class in Linq to Sql is marked with the `TableAttribute` attribute and it's `Name` property contains the name you need. We may use this:

```
public static string GetTableName<TEntity>(this Table<TEntity> MyTable) 
                            where TEntity : class
{
    Type type = typeof(TEntity);
    object[] temp = type.GetCustomAttributes(
                           typeof(System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute), 
                           true);
    if (temp.Length == 0)
        return null;
    else
        return (temp[0] as System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute).Name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed work. In my case though I do not have attributes on the tables. I create the classes manually in the designer and just use the class name. Any way to get the type of the entities that way?

Comment: Forget my previous comment. I saw how you got the entity type and understood what to do. I'll mark this as answer and post my modified version below. Many thanks!

Comment: @user643192 If the name of `TEntity` class equals the name of the table, it would be as easy as `typeof(TEntity).Name`

Comment: It was very simple, but I couldn't get it because the test code I was writing wasn't in an extension method, so I couldn't figure out how to get hold of `TEntity` :(

Answer (score 2):

This should also work:

```
MyTable.Context.Mapping.GetTable(typeof(TEntity)).TableName
```

Comment: What is TEntity? I mean I know what it wants but where do I get it?

Comment: @msysmilu The question is how to get the db-table-name for a datatype/entity. So just replace TEntity with whatever datatype you are saving to the database.

Comment: Thanks @Rolf, did so and got "dbo.Tablename" wich does the job in a SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have attributes on my tables, I need to get the entity name, which is what Linq to SQL will use in this case, so based on Konstantin Vasilicov's answer, the extension method becomes:

```
    public static string GetTableName<TEntity>(this Table<TEntity> MyTable) where TEntity : class
    {
        string name = string.Empty;
        Type type;
        object[] attributes;

        type = typeof(TEntity);
        attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute), true);

        if (attributes.Length > 0)
            name = ((TableAttribute)attributes[0]).Name;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                return name;

         return type.Name;
    }
```

Comment: Still, you don't need to write that long `MyTable.Context.GetTable(type).ElementType.Name`. It actually equals to `typeof(TEntity).Name` or in the context of your method just `type.Name`

Comment: Also if `GetCustomAttributes` returns an empty array, you would probably get an `IndexOutOfRanage` exception as you try to access the zero-indexed element without `Length` check.

Comment: Gosh, I'm so bad... Amended it again. Surely now it should be bullet-proof.